# Playing FLAC audio files on iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, core-audio, flac

I have a FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec) audio file that I need to play in my iOS application. I'm totally new in this area and know next to nothing about any audio frameworks or APIs for playing audio. I've looked at [Origami Engine](https://github.com/ap4y/OrigamiEngine) but i'm not entirely sure if that's what I need.

Answer (score 1):

No built-in facility of iOS allows for FLAC playing, so either convert to AAC or ALAC, or else use whatever third-party code you like.